# Cannot make lights visible in Render mode

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, lighting

I have set up area lights in Blender, with Ray Visibility set to check the Camera option. However, when I go to Viewport Render, the lights are not visible. I also have set the Scene Lights options enabled.

Is there another setting that could be causing the lights not to be visible on render?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions here, either:

- You don't have any object in your scene (you have hidden the only object of your scene, which is a cube, see the *Outliner*)
- The strength of your light is not high enough
- You have disabled the Scene Lights option in the *Viewport Shading* panel

Comment: Thank you for your response. I checked on those, but I'm still having the issue. The light does show on the object when I unhide it, but the light itself is not visible from the base

Comment: the lamp itself is not visible, you need to create a fake object (that has an Emission material), or create a cube with volumetric that contains your scene